# Newbie to VBA, Need a tricky function

Tags: vba, excel

Thanks in advance for any help...

(This is for a military unit to help keep track of which Service Members need to do which trainings.)

I need to take a bunch of data (on different sheets, all exported from the same location and formatted exactly the same) and copy them into one master sheet, but with the data inverted...

I have a bunch of sheets (like 25) with a list of names (and other administrative data) that shows who has completed a specific training, each sheet being for a different training. Instead of deficiencies by training, I'd like to have deficiencies by name.

The exported data is always formatted like so:

```
Title of Training

Last 4  Last Name   First Name  Rank    Unit    MOS Skill Level Most Recent
xxxx    Last        First       RNK     Unit    MOS SkillLevel  Date
```

I'd like a Master Sheet that looks like this:

```
Training Deficiencies

Last 4  Last Name   First Name  Rank    Unit    MOS TitleA  TitleB  etc
xxxx    Last        First       RNK     Unit    MOS   x        x     x
xxxx    Last        First       RNK     Unit    MOS            x     
xxxx    Last        First       RNK     Unit    MOS   x        x
```

Skill Level and Most Recent will be different for each training, and are irrelevant for the master sheet. The Titles (TitleA, TitleB, etc) can each be copied from Cell(1,1) of the respective sheet, and is also the title of the sheet itself.

I created a sheet with everyone in the unit, so my first step is to create the master sheet (I just delete the whole sheet and create it again):

```
Sheets("MasterSheet").Delete
Sheets("DataSheet").Copy After:=Sheets("DataSheet")
ActiveSheet.Name = "MasterSheet"
Cells(1, 1).Value = "'Master Sheet"
```

What I can't figure out how to do is loop through the Last4 on the Master Sheet and compare them against the Last4 in each training sheet.

So for each training sheet:

1. I want to create a new column on the MasterSheet with the training title as the column heading
2. Loop through each name on the training sheet and find that Service Member's row.
3. Put an "X" in the respective training column for that Service Member.

After that, I'd like each Service Member to be highlighted Green, Yellow, or Red based on the number of X's in their row. I think once I get the data copied I'll be able to figure out the highlighting and other formatting.

Thanks again for your help. I can't begin to express how much time this will save (it's currently done by hand). I've been on Google all day and I can find snippets of stuff but I don't really know how to put it all together. I'm using Excel 2007. I have an IT background and understand some code, but it's been a very very long time since I've done some real coding, and VBA is really confusing me.

Thanks again for your help in advance!

Comment: Have you tried using a Pivot Table?

Comment: Unfortunately, your question is too broad to be answered. StackOverflow is not a "do-my-coding-work-for-me" place, but a place where *specific* programming questions can be asked and answered with *specific* solutions. You are asking us to give you a "ready-to-go" recipe, and that is not how this place works

Answer (score 0):

I would do like this

- create a scripting.dictionary
- add all last4 from all sheets to the dictionary
- loop the dictionary and output all keys on the master sheet and set the value for each key to the row number
- loop all sheets again and look up the row number in the dictionary and set cell to 1
- create a formula to sum per row and use conditional formatting for colors
  (And use cell format "'x';;' if "x" is a hard requirement)